# An addition theorem for three functions similar to $\sin,\cos$ and $\sinh,\cosh$ and one / some questions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, generating-functions, cyclic-groups, trigonometric-functions

Define the functions $t_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{3n+k}}{(3n+k)!}}$ for $k=0,1,2$. The functions then satisfy:
$
\begin{pmatrix}\exp(x) \\ \exp(\omega x) \\ \exp(\omega^2 x)\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1 & \omega & \omega^2 \\1 & \omega^2 & \omega\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}t_0(x) \\ t_1(x) \\ t_2(x)\end{pmatrix}$
where $\omega = \exp(2\pi i / 3)$.

As might be known, the matrix in the equation is the character table of the cyclic group $C_3$ and also a Vandermonde matrix. Using this last matrix equation one can prove the following addition theorem:

$\begin{pmatrix}t_0(x+y) \\ t_1(x+y) \\ t_2(x+y)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}t_0(x) & t_2(x)  & t_1(x) \\ t_1(x) & t_0(x) & t_2(x)\\ t_2(x) & t_1(x) & t_0(x)\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}t_0(y)\\t_1(y)  \\ t_2(y)\end{pmatrix}$

As might be known the matrix in the last equation is a circulant matrix, which is also the group matrix $(x_{gh^{-1}})_{g,h\in G}$ as defined by Dedekind.
Now it is clear how to do this construction for every cyclic group $C_n$, which we just did for the cyclic group $C_3$, namely define the functions $f_g(x)$, $g\in C_n$using the character table of $C_n$.

If one takes the determinant of the last matrix, one can show (using the theory of circular matrix) that this is equal to one:
$t_0(x)^3+t_1(x) ^3+t_2(x)^3-3t_0(x)t_1(x)t_2(x) = 1$ for all $x$.

Those functions $t_k$ are similar to $\sinh,\cosh$ where we have replaced the cyclic group $C_2$ with the cyclic group $C_3$.

Now it would be fun to define similar $\sin,\cos$ functions which satisfy an addition theorem and "behave" with respect to differentation like $\sin,\cos$:

Let $\gamma = \exp(\frac{2 \pi i}{9})$ and set:

- $s_0(x) := \frac{1}{\gamma} t_0(\gamma x)$
- $s_2(x) := s'_0(x) = t_2(\gamma x)$ because of $t'_0(x) = t_2(x)$
- $s_1(x) := s'_2(x) = \gamma t_1(\gamma x)$ because of $t'_2(x) = t_1(x)$

From $t'_1(x) = t_0(x)$ it follows that $s_1'(x) = \omega s_0(x)$. Using the addition theorem for $t_k$ and the definition of $s_k$ we get after some concentrated calculations the following addition theorem:

$$\begin{pmatrix}s_0(x+y) \\ s_1(x+y) \\ s_2(x+y)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\gamma s_0(x) & \frac{s_2(x)}{\gamma^2} & \frac{s_1(x)}{\gamma^2} \\ \gamma s_1(x) & \gamma s_0(x) & \gamma s_2(x)\\ \gamma s_2(x) & \frac{s_1(x)}{\gamma^2} & \gamma s_0(x)\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}s_0(y)\\s_1(y)  \\ s_2(y)\end{pmatrix}$$

The determinant of this last matrix is equal to:

$$\gamma s_0(x)^3+s_2(x)^3+\frac{s_1(x)^3}{\gamma^3}-3s_0(x) s_1(x) s_2(x) = t_0(x\gamma)^3+t_1(x\gamma) ^3+t_2(x\gamma)^3-3t_0(x\gamma)t_1(x\gamma)t_2(x\gamma) = 1$$

Notice that this is the equivalent version for the group $C_3$ as is for the group $C_2$ the version:

$$\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$$

My naive questions are:

1. Are there more "similar properties" which the functions $s_k$ share with $\sin,\cos$?
2. Is it possible to derive an infinite product representation of $s_1$?
3. Does there exist an $x \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $t_0(x)$ or $t_1(x)$ or $t_2(x)$ is an algebraic number or a rational number?
4. Can we use the functions $t_k$ to "parametrize" integer solutions of the equation:

$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz = n^3$$

There has been some research from R.D. Carmichael in this direction:

R. D. Carmichael, On the representation of numbers in the form x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 22 (1915)
See also: http://oeis.org/A074232

There has also been research from D. Lehmer concerning the "generalized Euler numbers" defined as the coefficients of the reciprocal of $t_0(x)$
(see: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333339254_LEHMER%27S_GENERALIZED_EULER_NUMBERS_IN_HYPERGEOMETRIC_FUNCTIONS_LEHMER%27S_GENERALIZED_EULER_NUMBERS_IN_HYPERGEOMETRIC_FUNCTIONS )

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227161/connection-between-cyclic-group-and-exponential-function

Comment: related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411945/three-questions-about-three-functions-similar-to-sin-cos